# Kusto Query Language: Sum a column

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

How do you perform the equivalent of an SQL sum `SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name` in Kusto Query Language for Azure Data Explorer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
app("your-app").tableName 
| summarize sum(columnToSum)
```

You don't need to have a "by" statement in your summarize, but you can add it for performing a group by, for example,

```
app("your-app").tableName
| summarize sum(columnToSum) by columnToGroupBy
```